# additionalProperties eliminates all model properties

Tags: java, swagger

I have run into this issue now with implementing arbitrary field behaviour with `additionalProperties`. Below is my model with additional properties.

```
"CObject": {
 "type": "object",
 "properties": {
  "_id": {
   "type": "string"
  },
  "createdAt": {
   "type": "string",
   "format": "date-time"
  },
  "updatedAt": {
   "type": "string",
   "format": "date-time"
  }
 },
 "additionalProperties": {
  "type": "string"
 }
}
```

Indeed the only change I see in the generated java client is that my `CObject.java` now sub-classes HashMap class. I expected that a call to `put([key],[value])` on `CObject` would just add a new property in the request body. On running a test, I realized that all properties within `CObject` are absent in the final request body. So, the client only sends a request body with properties defined arbitrarily and eliminates all other properties defined in the specification. Am using the latest `swagger-codegen(2.1.6 snapshot)`. how can I get past this issue???
**NB** I don't want the map values to appear under their own property, I want the key value pairs to appear under the same hierarchy as the rest of the properties defined in the spec.

Answer (score 0):

In the JSON you provided, "additionalProperties" is just a property name and its type is string. Let's say the property name is "keyValuePair", then the correct way to use `additionalProperties` is

```
"keyValuePair": {
    {
        "type": "object",
        "additionalProperties": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this, however, I have edited the question to further refine what I want, since I already tried this.

Comment: can you give an example (JSON) of what CObject looks like?

Comment: If this is how CBObject looks without any additional params:
     "CBObject": {
      "createdAt": null,
      "updatedAt": null,
      "_id": true
     }
after calling CBObject.put("name","bengi"), it should look like this;
      "CBObject": {
      "createdAt": null,
      "updatedAt": null,
      "_id": true,
      "name":"bengi"
     }